# How to use select box related on another select box?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

How to use related select boxes in Symfony ?

Let's say, I have a select list containing compagnies and another containing employees of the selected company.  How do I define those in Symfony? 
I have already created all the Javascript related code but when submitting my form and having errors on some fields, the all "sub" select fields are reset to null.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

EDIT : As the question seems to be misunderstood, I'll add some precisions :

### Description :

1. I have an entity Company containing a list of Employees using a @OneToMany relation.
2. When I select a company in a select/dropdown list, the second dropdown list containing the employees is updated via jQuery. **That part is done, works perfectly**
3. When submitting the form without errors, the entity form solution works fine.
4. When submitting the form containing errors, the second dropdown list is containing **all** possible values. They are not filtered on the selected company.

### Tried solutions :

- My first idea was to use the **form entity** type, thinking the component could be binded somehow on another field. ie. update list of employees based on the value of the selected company.

*Not working, there is no way out of the box to do this. Even non out of the box solutions...*

- Then I thought about **manually passing** the selected company as **parameter** to the query builder of the second dropdown list.

*But when the form is created, the values are empty. The values are only set on **bindRequest**.*

- Thought about using the choice type. Delegating all filter functionnality to the UI via Javascript. Meaning when the page loads, an empty list appears and is populated by Javascript based on the selected company.

*This actually works, but I think there is no other word than really **really ugly programming** here.*

### PS :

Question has been asked here, on the Symfony2 mailing-list, on Twitter and the officiel Symfony 2 forum. I have of course searched each of those several times before posting my questions.

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: Not much code to share in fact. But added what I can.

Comment: At the beginning you chose employees of certain company via jQuery? So, after submitting form with errors this jquery code isn't work and you see all employees. Check firebug console or chrome deleveloper tools console for js errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Concerning what you already tried, I think you should retry your first/second ideas:

> My first idea was to use the form entity type, thinking the component
>   could be binded somehow on another field. ie. update list of employees
>   based on the value of the selected company.

You can populate the employees select box using the `entity` type.
All you have to do is to define the good options:

```php
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('employee', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Entity\Employee',
                'query_builder' => function ($repository) use($options) {
                    return $repository
                        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                        ->where('e.company = :company')
                        ->setParameter('company', $options['companyId'])
                    ;
                },
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Entity\Foo', 'companyId' => null);
    }
}
```

> Then I thought about manually passing the selected company as
>   parameter to the query builder of the second dropdown list.

The example here filters the employees list based on the companyId form's option.
You can modify this behavior by filtering directly on the company present in the form's data.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $companyId = $builder->getData()->getCompanyId();
    $builder
        ->add('employee', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Entity\Employee',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($companyId) {
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where('e.company = :company')
                    ->setParameter('company', $companyId)
                ;
            },
        ))
    ;
}
```

You still have to implement the `getEmployee()` and `setEmployee()` methods in your `Entity\Foo` class.

> But when the form is created, the values are empty. The values are only set on
>   bindRequest.

No. Values are set when you create you form using form factory (third argument),
OR when you call `$form->setData($foo);`. Data is modified when you `bind` new inputs to the form.

*There could be a problem with this approach: it's possible that the employee id bound to the form is not available in the form choice list, because you changed the company (and thus the employees).*

Comment: Thank you very much Florian :) That helped me out you can not even believe how !!!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. You must use form events. My code example with country, region, city relations.

```
namespace Orfos\UserBundle\Form\Type;

///import form events namespace
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{

    private $request;

    public function __construct($class, $request, $doctrine)
    {
        parent::__construct($class);
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        //other fields

        $locale = $this->request->getLocale();

        $builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Orfos\CoreBundle\Entity\Country',
            'property' => $locale . 'name',
            'label' => 'register.country.label',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->select('c', 't')
                                ->join('c.translations', 't');
            },
        ));

        $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();
        $refreshRegion = function ($form, $country) use ($factory, $locale) {
                    $form->add($factory->createNamed('entity', 'region', null, array(
                                'class' => 'Orfos\CoreBundle\Entity\Region',
                                'property' => $locale . 'name',
                                'label' => 'register.region.label',
                                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($country) {
                                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('region')
                                            ->select('region', 'translation')
                                            ->innerJoin('region.country', 'country')
                                            ->join('region.translations', 'translation');

                                    if ($country instanceof Country) {
                                        $qb = $qb->where('region.country = :country')
                                                ->setParameter('country', $country);
                                    } elseif (is_numeric($country)) {
                                        $qb = $qb->where('country.id = :country_id')
                                                ->setParameter('country_id', $country);
                                    } else {
                                        $qb = $qb->where('country.id = 1');
                                    }

                                    return $qb;
                                }
                            )));
                };
        $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();
        $refreshCity = function($form, $region) use ($factory, $locale) {
                    $form->add($factory->createNamed('entity', 'city', null, array(
                                'class' => 'Orfos\CoreBundle\Entity\City',
                                'property' => $locale . 'name',
                                'label' => 'register.city.label',
                                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($region) {
                                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('city')
                                            ->select('city', 'translation')
                                            ->innerJoin('city.region', 'region')
                                            ->innerJoin('city.translations', 'translation');

                                    if ($region instanceof Region) {
                                        $qb = $qb->where('city.region = :region')
                                                ->setParameter('region', $region);
                                    } elseif (is_numeric($region)) {
                                        $qb = $qb->where('region.id = :region_id')
                                                ->setParameter('region_id', $region);
                                    } else {
                                        $qb = $qb->where('region.id = 1');
                                    }

                                    return $qb;
                                }
                            )));
                };

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshRegion, $refreshCity) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    $data = $event->getData();

                    if ($data == null){
                        $refreshRegion($form, null);
                        $refreshCity($form, null);
                    }

                    if ($data instanceof Country) {
                        $refreshRegion($form, $data->getCountry()->getRegions());
                        $refreshCity($form, $data->getRegion()->getCities());
                    }
                });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshRegion, $refreshCity) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    $data = $event->getData();

                    if (array_key_exists('country', $data)) {
                        $refreshRegion($form, $data['country']);
                    }
                    if (array_key_exists('region', $data)) {
                        $refreshCity($form, $data['region']);
                    }                    
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I could create from your idea a generic type to create chained dropdowns.

Comment: Hello Pivasyk. Your input on this post is very interesting. Thank you for that. Could you please tell me if country, region and city are set in one entity or are they 3 different entities linked together?

Comment: @Marc, hm... I don't understand your question...
It's 3 different entities with relation one to many
the 4th entity is user linked to city, region and country

Answer (score 0):

You can create action, that will be return json array with employees of company.
When the list of companies changed you must request this action by ajax and create select list of employees.

Form controller action:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/job", name="_demo_job")
 * @Template()
 */
public function jobAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new JobType());

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $data = $form->getData();
        // some operations with form data
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Conroller, that return employees by company in json:

```php
/**
 * Finds all employees by company
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/show", name="employees_by_category")
 */
public function listByCompanyAction($id)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $company = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Company')->find($id);

        // create array for json response
        $empoloyees = array();
        foreach ($company->getEmployees() as $employee) {
            $empoloyees[] = array($employee->getId(), $employee->getName());
        }

        $response = new Response(json_encode($empoloyees));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
    return new Response();
}
```

Form template:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form_company').change(function() {
            var companyId = $(this).val();
            $.post('{{ route }}/' + companyId + '/show', function(data) {
                // last selected employee
                var selectedVal = $('option:selected', '#form_employee').attr('value');

                $('#form_employee option').remove();
                for (i in data) {
                    // create option with employee
                    var option = $('<option></option>').
                        attr('value', data[i][0]).
                        text(data[i][1]);
                    // set selected employee
                    if (data[i][0] == selectedVal) {
                        option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                    // append to employee to employees select
                    $('#form_employee').append(option);
                }
            }, 'json');
        })

        // request employees by company
        $('#form_company').change();
    })

</script>
```

```twig
<form action="{{ path('_demo_job') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For more detail example you should describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the effort but as you might have noticed, in my questions I clearly stated all the jQuery json part is already implemented.

Comment: In my variant selects are not reset. You must share your js and form builder action that I try find the problem.