# Display contents of Select Box based on another Select Box in Symfony 2.1

Tags: jquery, symfony, listbox, symfony-2.1

The answer at [How to use select box related on another select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052916/how-to-use-select-box-related-on-another-select-box) helped me get started, and my code works if I hard code the id of the first select box into the second select box. However, if I try to use the actual form value, I get a

> Notice: Undefined index: my_group

Here is the code for the drop down box I want to display based on a group select drop box:

```
  $builder->add('subscriptiontype', 'entity',
        array(
            'label' => 'profile.edit.my_subscription_type', 
            'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            'empty_value' => 'Select subscription type',
            'property' => 'subscription_title',
            'class' => 'SDMarketplaceBundle:SubscriptionType',
            'multiple' => false,
            'attr' => array('onchange' => '',  'class' => ''),
            'query_builder' => function($repository) use ($options){ 
                return $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('j')
                        ->where('j.isActive = :active AND j.valid_until > :timenow AND j.group = :group_id')
                        ->setParameter('active', 1)
                        ->setParameter('timenow', new \DateTime('now'))
                        ->setParameter('group_id', $options['my_group'])
                    ->orderBy('j.subscription_title', 'ASC');
                    }
        )
    );
```

If I change **$options['my_group']** to an actual number which is the id of the group, it displays correctly. Here is the html code output when I actually put an id in place of **$options['my_group']**:

```
<select id="fos_user_profile_form_my_group" name="fos_user_profile_form[my_group]" required="required"><option value="">Select group</option><option value="5">administrator</option><option value="2" selected="selected">instructor</option><option value="3">proofreader</option><option value="1">student</option><option value="4">translator</option></select>
```

Any help on what I am doing incorrectly or missing?

----Apologies for my extremely belated response as I did not see your post (but thank you.) Here is my controller code for the showAction:

```
public function showAction()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        $myGroup = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SDMarketplaceBundle:Groups')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getMyGroup())); //retrieve the group selected by this user
        $subscriptiontype = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SDMarketplaceBundle:Subscriptiontype')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getSubscriptiontype())); //retrieve the subscription type title for this user
        $accounttype = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SDMarketplaceBundle:AccountType')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getMyAccountType())); //retrieve the account type name for this user
        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'), 
        array(
            'user' => $user, 
            'myGroup' => $myGroup,
            'subscriptiontype' => $subscriptiontype->getSubscriptionTitle(),
            'accounttype' => $accounttype->getAccountName(),
            'statusCode' => $user->getStatusName($user->getStatusCode())
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Why should `my_group` be stored at $options? at `buildForm()` $options stores your form type's options. You can inject the selected group to your form when you create it in your controller. Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out
http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos

You can see a demo here:
http://sf2.showmethecode.es/app.php/ejemplo/selects-dependientes