# Two related EntityType fields in Symfony 5.2 Forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, php-7.2, symfony5

I have in my database a user entity that has an address. This address is also an entity that has a landmark (string), and a ManyToOne relationship with a street entity, and the street entity has a name(string) and a ManyToOne relationship with a state entity (that only has a name(string) attribute).

So an address is like: **State -> Street -> Address**

My goal is to make a form that will let the user choose a state from a list (retrieved from the database), then choose a street from another list (Also retrieved from the database, but only including the streets of the selected state).

I tried many methods and referred to the docs, but couldn't make it out. The best solution i could implement so far is to make a separate custom AddressType that contains one EntityType for the streets list, and group the streets by states. Here is the actual code for this:

- Address

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AddressRepository::class)
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $landMark;

    /**
     * @var Street
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Street::class, inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $street;
}
```

- Street

```
/**
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StreetRepository::class)
*/
class Street
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var State
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=State::class, inversedBy="streets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $state;
}
```

- State

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StateRepository::class)
*/
class State
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

- **UserType**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('address', AddressType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

- **AddressType**

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('landMark', TextType::class)
            ->add('street', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Street::class,
                'group_by' => ChoiceList::groupBy($this, 'state'),
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Address::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052916/how-to-use-select-box-related-on-another-select-box

Comment: This post is more about form validation, my problem is in the form creation. The guy in the post handled the problem i have using jQuery, i want to do it inside Symfony instead. @ehymel